# Remove EF elimina mas registros C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo una tabla donde estoy guardando, un id de usuario y un id de programa (aqui se guardan los accesos a X programas por X usuarios)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestion es que tengo una vista donde tengo un boton de borrar donde elimino el acceso a UN SOLO programa por usuario, pero cuando trato de eliminar 1, elimina todas la coincidencias del ID de usuario (`sega_usuario`)

```
                using (var ctx=new ModelContext())
                {
                    var entidad = ctx.SegAccesos.Single(x => x.sega_usuario == idUsuario &&
                                                       x.sega_programa == idPrograma);
                    ctx.SegAccesos.Remove(entidad);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                    return "OK";
                }
```

Trato de eliminar el registro 56 del usuario 4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando termino de ejecutar y reviso la vista y la base de datos, veo que se fue todo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que hay mal con el código de eliminación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algo que no estas tomando en cuenta y es algo que te puede ayudar a evitar este tipo de eliminaciones masivas.

Resulta que usas una tabla sin Identificador o primary key, entonces esto hace que no tengas una validación directa con la tabla mediante el contexto.

Cuando haces esto:

```
var entidad = ctx.SegAccesos.Single(x => x.sega_usuario == idUsuario &&
                                                       x.sega_programa == idPrograma);
```

Resulta que extraes un solo elemento con el sega_usuario y el sega_programa que coincida, pero lamentablemente en tu tabla, los 2 registros coinciden con la información y esto hace que se eliminen ambos.

Para evitar eso, crea una tabla con un primary key con el que puedas identificar el registro que realmente quieras eliminar.

Entonces con esto tu código quedaría así:

```
using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
{
    var entidad = ctx.SegAccesos.Single(x => x.id = id && 
                                        x.sega_usuario == idUsuario &&
                                        x.sega_programa == idPrograma);
    ctx.SegAccesos.Remove(entidad);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return "OK";
}
```

Y con esto ya tienes un campo mas con el que puedes validar y que este identificador no se puede repetir, entonces no podrás eliminar algún otro registro ya que no tienen el mismo identificador(primary key).

Comment: aunque valido, te dejo dos detalles.. primero, los dos registros son distintos.. el id de programa no es el mismo, con lo cual, no deberia eliminar los dos (o EF es peor de lo que pensaba), luego de eso, si agregas una id unica, entonces no tendrias que andar buscando por los 3 campos, porque con el unico alcanza.. no? creo que el problema esta en otro lado...

Comment: El id que tomas en cuenta al parecer no es un id de la tabla, caso contrario lo tomaría en cuenta EF y al parecer no lo toma en cuenta. Mas parece un indicador de registros que te presentan en la pantalla (Asegúrarse de revisar los datos una vez se ejecute la linea, a ver si te retorna esos valores "diferentes"). 
Y si, una vez se implemente el id ya no seria relevante poner los 3 campos de validación.

Comment: yo no soy el del problema Marcos.. solo indico algunas cosas que parecen problemas con tu respuesta ;)

Comment: Pues me parecen muy acertadas, solo ayudo con Feedback.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso es mejor usar el `where` porque estas tratando eliminar un dato especifico

```
var entidad = ctx.SegAccesos.Where(x => x.sega_usuario == idUsuario &&
                                                       x.sega_programa == idPrograma).FirstOrDefault();
```

quedando como resultado de esta manera

```
using (var ctx=new ModelContext())
 {
   var entidad = ctx.SegAccesos.Where(x => x.sega_usuario == idUsuario &&
      x.sega_programa == idPrograma).FirstOrDefault();
  ctx.SegAccesos.Remove(entidad);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
  return "OK";
}
```

aqui puedes ver la diferencia entre `Single` y `FirstOrDefault`

**[Single](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-6.0)**
*Devuelve un único elemento específico de una secuencia o un valor predeterminado si no se encuentra ese elemento.*

**[firstordefault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0)**
*Devuelve el primer elemento de una secuencia o un valor predeterminado si no se encuentra ningún elemento.*